# Assign name to count aggregate Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Hei there.
I've got a big problem with my Rails app. I need to select the user who got the biggest amount of followers in the last day. I've got a model called Relationship which connect followers and followed users.
Here is my code:

```
wins = Relationship.select("followed_id, count(follower_id) AS num_foll").where(:created_at => (Time.now-1.day)..Time.now).group(:followed_id).order("count(follower_id) DESC")
```

I didn't select the first one because I want to handle multiple winners. In fact, after this step I've got:

```
max_followers = wins.select("num_foll").first.num_foll
wins.each() do |win| [...]
```

But Rails can't access this num_foll, throwing me the error:

```
no such column: num_foll.
```

Is there some convention or some auto-assigned name for the count aggregate? I really can't figure it out. Consider that the query seems to work if I choose only the first one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `max_followers = wins.first.num_foll` ?

Answer (score 0):

When you write `wins.select("num_foll")` you reassign this select `Relationship.select("followed_id, count(follower_id) AS num_foll")`. Yann VERY is right.

Comment: Oh, it worked! Thanks a lot. I was misleaded by the 'select' word!